# How to take a percentage of a Credit Card transaction?

Tags: e-commerce, credit-card

Essentially what I am trying to do is setup a work flow similar to PayPal.  I have created an application that allows my clients to accept online donations and what I want to do is take % percent of that transaction off the top. The problems I have run into are:

- Authroize does not allow me to take on an additional fee that is paid out to my account
- I could run a report every month on all my clients transactions to determine what they owe but this is less than ideal
- All of the companies I looked at do not allow for aggregation where by all of the donation systems pay into my account then I remit payment to my clients

Does anyone know of a company that allows for this or is my only option here going to be to setup my own Payment Gateway or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: So you can't just add your percentage, before submitting it?, then subtract that part and have it go to a different account?

Comment: Potentially, yes, that would work but it becomes a bit of management nightmare because:

When a user submits a donation I would need to calculate out the percent that I am owed, process the actual donation to my clients account, then create a new transaction to turn around and charge my client for the percentage amount. This would require my clients to keep some sort of Credit Card info on file with me so I would have something to charge agasint.  Ideally I want the fee to come out automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro). It allows for payments to be sent to two parties. This means you can take your cut and sent the rest to the other recipient.